# Dropdown submenu on bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I just wanna ask why is it the dropdown submenu on bootstrap is not working, i just followed the instructions in this link: (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html) but still the dropdown sub menu on a submenu did not appear. By the way I did not change or override classes in the CSS.

Here's my code! :)

```
<li class='dropdown'><a class='dropdown-toggle active' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><img src = 'images/forbank.png' height = 35 width = 35>Banking<span class='caret'></span></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li class = 'dropdown-submenu'><a tabindex='-1' href='#'><span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-cog'> </span>  Transaction</a>
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu' role = 'menu'>
                            <li><a tabindex='-1' href='#'> Withdrawal / Deposit </a></li>
                            <li><a tabindex='-1' href='#'> Fixed Deposit </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li role='separator' class='divider'></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'> </span> Summaries </a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'> </span>  Settings </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: I would suggest using the newest version of Bootstrap. Version 2.3.2 is out of date, version 3.3.5 is the latest. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please verify if your the instructions you have followed corresponds to your bootstrap version.

Additionally, you can try to include this few lines of CSS to make things work.

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: I just read that the class dropdown-submenu has been removed to the latest version of CCS and there is no alternative class for the latest version T.T what should I do?

Comment: Create new CSS file, paste the code above and link the CSS to your html

Answer (score 1):

I did it, but the problem is the the submenu for "Withdrawal/Deposit" and "Fixed Deposit" is blocking the parent submenu "Transaction", it does not go to the right of it during hover. Here is my code now.

```
        <li class='dropdown'><a id = 'dLabel' class='dropdown-toggle active' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><img src = 'images/forbank.png' height = 35 width = 35>Banking<span class='caret'></span></a>
            <ul class='dropdown-menu multi-level' role='menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>
                <li class = 'dropdown-submenu'>
                <a  tabindex = '-1' href='#'><span class = 'glyphicon glyphicon-cog'> </span>  Transaction </a>
                    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                        <li><a tabindex='-1' href='#'> Withdrawal / Deposit </a></li>
                        <li><a tabindex='-1' href='#'> Fixed Deposit </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li role='separator' class='divider'></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt'> </span> Summaries </a></li>
                <li><a href='#'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench'> </span>  Settings </a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```